# Akka: How to remove child actor

Tags: java, akka

I have a parent actor and children. Each child actors controlls a device. I give an uuid as to all child actors when I create them.

Each child actor is created by device configuration, when the configuration is changed, i would like to recreate the actor by:

- stopping the old one:

  final Future stopped = gracefulStop(actorRef, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  Await.result(stopped, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
- recreating a new one:

  context.actorOf(Props.create(
      GateActor.class,
      () -> new GateActor(hardwareRouterActorRef, settings)),
      settings.getUuid())

But it throws an exception:

`akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [6237255c-851b-47d2-ac31-03c7635e6537] is not unique!`

I think the gracefulStop code not removes the children actor, my question is: how can I remove the child actor?

I have also tried to remove an actor by a PoisonPill:

```
actorRef.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), getSelf());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/actors.html#Graceful_Stop) :

> Keep in mind that an actor stopping and its name being deregistered
>   are separate events which happen asynchronously from each other.
>   Therefore it may be that you will find the name still in use after
>   gracefulStop() returned. In order to guarantee proper deregistration,
>   only reuse names from within a supervisor you control and only in
>   response to a Terminated message, i.e. not for top-level actors.

So you should perform the creation of the actor with the recycled name only after the reception of the `Terminated` message for which a supervisor actor should register to.